# How to get apps using significant energy programatically like battery icon from MacBook

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos

I am trying to get a significant energy consuming app list as it shows in the battery icon in MacBook programmatically.

![enter image description here][1]

Like Below...
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bapoI.png

Any help would be appreciated.

I tried to use the following top command in a code but it's not working.

```
top  -stats -l 1 -O pid,command,cpu,idlew,power -o power -d
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show what research you've undertaken, what you've already tried, what didn't work, code samples etc. Please read [ask] and [mcve] and then [edit] your question showing the _minimum_ code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @AshleyMills I have started exploring this topic. I only tried command line using Pipe() .thanks for the suggestions and guideline.As I am new here I will try to follow them.

Answer (score 0):

Try using -

```
top -stats pid,command,cpu,idlew,power -o power -d
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at `IOPMPowerSource`

Apple have sample `cpp` source here… https://opensource.apple.com/source/PowerManagement/PowerManagement-703.1.5/AppleSmartBatteryManager/AppleSmartBattery.cpp.auto.html

Also, try running `ioreg -irc IOPMPowerSource` in the terminal.

Comment: That's part of the driver kit, it doesn't look related to the  question.